# Is there a way to find out why HttpClient POST fails on a simple form site that otherwise works in webBrowser control?

Tags: c#, post, httpclient

I am writing some C# code to automate a webpage form submission that functions in WebBrowser control, but fails with other means such as HttpClient or WebRequest. I am trying to figure out what is wrong with the POST request, as this is where I encounter problems.

In a nutshell:

1.) I receive the HTML of a page, read a base64 string encoded Captcha image and a hidden key.

2.) Pass the base64 string to a python script I wrote that uses OpenCV to reconstruct the image from string, OCR the figures, solve the math and return it's 'guess' (~90% accuracy).

3.) POST the captcha guess and hidden key (+ 2 other simple fields) and read the response to validate submission.

I am working in VS2019 and have been able to create a 'hack' version of my goal by automating the form based WebBrowser control via the Document class using the extracted data and it works, however this is very inefficient and requires the use of Forms/controls, making it 'bulky' and difficult to integrate into a larger program.

I have examined POST data and headers sent during normal website operation via FireFox and have replicated them in my HttpClient code, but while I can receive a response, it is only one that tells me something went wrong. I do not receive a response that contains an expected server-application generated error when POSTing intentionally bad data, such as missing field or bad Captcha answer for which there are specific errors.

My gut is telling me the server is choking on my 'tauth' field or something in the request before it ever gets to parsing my submitted data and this is where I have been stuck for days trying everything I could think of, but is becoming more of a pain than the issue it was meant to solve. For the record, I do not do a lot of web work...

The first attempt:

```
private static async Task DoPOSThttpAsync(string c, string a, string t)
    {
        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "captcha", c }, //ex. c == "17"
            { "taddress", a },//a == "moz6XAHSMTNo7PjAa1czVaPhspJszfpTDZ" - testnet wallet address
            { "amount", "0.01" },
            { "tauth", @t } //hidden key
        };

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values); //tauth gets mangled here?
        HttpClient hclient = new HttpClient();
        hclient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

        var response = await hclient.PostAsync("https://testnet-faucet.mempool.co/", content);
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(responseString);
    }
```

and an attempt with HttpWebRequest:

```cs
static void DoPOSTweb(string c, string a, string t)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://testnet-faucet.mempool.co/");

        var postData = "captcha=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(c);
        postData += "&taddress=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(a);//a == "moz6XAHSMTNo7PjAa1czVaPhspJszfpTDZ" - testnet wallet address
        postData += "&amount=" + Uri.EscapeDataString("0.01");
        postData += "&tauth=" + @t; // Uri.EscapeDataString(@tAuth); //mangles tauth?
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

        request.Timeout = 5000;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        request.Host = "testnet-faucet.mempool.co";
        request.Referer = "https://testnet-faucet.mempool.co/";
        request.UserAgent = @agentName; //Copied from Firefox

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Respons: Ok");
                System.Console.WriteLine();
                var encoding = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8;
                using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encoding))
                {
                    string responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Data: " + responseText);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When a successful form submission is made with correct data, the page returns with text indicating a Tx of tBtc has been sent along with Tx ID. If unsuccessful, the page reports various errors related to the reason such as 'invalid spam filter', 'invalid testnet address', 'invalid amount' and 'limits exceeded'. The error 'try again' is used for general errors, including submissions made after ~10mins without a page refresh or hidden key field error and is the one I receive in the response after POST requests. Assuming that my POST data is correct, I should receive the Tx ID response.

Html data extraction code is the same used in the working WebBrowser control version, so I know I have the correct data, just not sure I am POSTing it right? All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use Fiddler to capture the request that is sent (a) from your browser and (b) from your program. Check carefully for any differences, however small, and account for  all of them.

Comment: @JohnWu Thanks for the suggestion, it helped not with the POST request (they were identical a & b), but in discovering the need to retrieve a PNG after the original GET that was acting as a time validation flag for the following POST request to succeed. Page throws an error even in browsers if idle too long when submitted. Never occurred to me that an img could be more than just an img (except maybe steganography). Code works great now.